# How to convert my phonegap Hello World project to Android APK?

Tags: android, cordova, phonegap-desktop-app

I am a beginner in android programming, so please bare with me.I am trying to convert phonegap Hello World([getting-started](http://docs.phonegap.com/getting-started/3-create-your-app/desktop/)) project to apk . Could any one explain to me what methods available and what steps it requires? Do i need cordova files to convert Hello World project to apk?If yes how to install it on phonegap?Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can do this phonegap Desktop /cli commands.

You can get detailed steps here at official site:

http://docs.phonegap.com/getting-started/3-create-your-app/desktop/

**---- EDIT -----**

You can generate/build apk on your desktop without using cloud by following methods:

**1) Cordova/phonegap CLI (Command Line Interface)**
http://docs.phonegap.com/en/3.5.0/guide_cli_index.md.html

**2) Using Eclipse**

http://www.webtutorialspoint.com/phone-gap/how-to-create-sample-phone-gap-app-in-eclipse-for-android/

Comment: Thanks for your reply . Is there any step by step tutorial on how to do it on desktop offline without using cloud ?

Comment: Without cloud.There are two ways kindly check my updated answer

Comment: Many thanks i followed the first link you provided and it was very helpfull.I created test1 project and tried to build it using this command: phonegap build android and i get this error:Error:Please install Android Target: "android-23" .I already installed sdk for android 4.2.2(android-17).Is there any cli command to change the target from android-23(Android 6) to android-17(4.2.2)?

Comment: You can add specific android platform with this command :`cordova platform add android@x.x.x`

Comment: i created the test project by this command: phonegap create test1.I get this error when using your command(phonegap platform add android@4.2.2) ,now How to fix it? :Error: Failed to fetch platform android@4.2.2
Probably this is either a connection problem, or platform spec is incorrect.Check your connection and platform name/version/URL.
Error: version not found: cordova-android@4.2.2

Comment: Yes 4.2.2 is not there...You can check the link https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/guide/platforms/android/

Comment: Also for 4.1.X you can try `phonegap platform add android@4.1.1`